# icon won't change color on hover once i add an anchor tag.

Tags: html, css

I have a social media widgets that i wanna include in my website. I have a grayscale and a colored image for each widget. The trick is to change the color of the widgets to grayscale to colored upon mouse hover. All seems to work correctly until i inserted  into the code. The hover no longer works. Could someone have an idea how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

here is the html code.

```
<html>
<header>
<title>image hover</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href= "style.css"/>
</header>
<body>
<div id = "wrapper">
<div id = "facebook"><a href = "https://www.facebook.com/pages/CIT-Care/138858432940938/"><img src = "images/facebook.fw.png"/></a></div>
<div id = "twitter"></div>
<div id = "googleplus"></div>
<div id = "whatsapp"></div>
<div id = "skype"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css:

```
body{margin: 0; border:0; padding: 0;}
#wrapper{width: 960px; margin: 50px auto; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #dedede;}
#facebook{background-image: url('images/facebook.fw.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; float: left; height: 52px; width: 52px;}
#facebook:hover{background-image:url('images/facebook1.fw.png');}
#twitter{background-image: url('images/twitter.fw.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; float: left; height: 52px; width: 52px; margin-left: 10px;}
#twitter:hover{background-image:url('images/twitter1.fw.png');}
#googleplus{background-image: url('images/googlep.fw.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; float: left; height: 52px; width: 52px; margin-left: 10px;}
#googleplus:hover{background-image:url('images/googlep1.fw.png');}
#whatsapp{background-image: url('images/whatsapp.fw.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; float: left; height: 52px; width: 52px; margin-left: 10px;}
#whatsapp:hover{background-image:url('images/whatsapp1.fw.png');}
#skype{background-image: url('images/skype.fw.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; float: left; height: 52px; width: 52px; margin-left: 10px;}
#skype:hover{background-image:url('images/skype1.fw.png');}
```

Comment: How to you think that somebody will answer a question with an incomprehensible CSS. Also a good idea to use http://jsfiddle.net/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change HTML elements on hover with CSS :hover.  What you can change with that is the CSS styling.  In this case, what you are wanting to do is change the BACKGROUND image from a B&G to the color one.  So, in your html you define this as a link, in your css you define its size, regular BACKGROUND image, and then (for example) #facebook a:hover {code stuff}

In other words, get rid of the  in the HTML, and instead use the CSS to define the original image and hover state image using the background image attribute.  Also, don't forget to define the dimensions for this area.

Answer (score 2):

The `:hover` probably works fine, it's just that you added the `img` tag in front of it and you can't see the change...

Comment: What should i do to see the change?

Comment: I suppose you should get rid of the `img` tag into the `anchor` or just hide it with css like this `#twitter:hover img { display:none;}`

Comment: But i will get rid of the colored image if  i do that and my hover won't have any effect.

Comment: But you have set the images as `background-image` on both normal and `:hover` state, you don't need the `img` tag. At least that's what I see in your code.

Comment: True but they are two different images. The normal one is the black and white image and the hover image is the colored image. Hope that's clear now.